# iTerm2 custom font location

Tags: terminal, homebrew, font, iterm

I am unable to add a custom font to iTerm2. When I install the font via `brew install font-fira-code`, it is installed in `/Users/my_user_name/Library/Fonts`. However, iTerm2 shows the system fonts only, i.e. those in `/System/Library/Fonts`.

How can I add a font from a custom location to iTerm2?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to install Powerline fonts
(https://github.com/powerline/fonts).

Try moving your font files to `/Library/Fonts`.